# "Could not find protoc command. Make sure protobuf is installed and your PATH environment is set"

Tags: python, windows

I am trying install imposm.parser library on python.

After I typed - `pip install imposm.parser`, it said it could not find protoc command.

but I have already got protobuf 2.6.1 library installed on python!? I don't understand.

Thanks
Andrew

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 4):

You need to download Protocol Compiler separately from Protocol Buffers library. Get it from [Google Developers Protocol Buffers Download](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/downloads) page.

Answer (score 0):

Most executables of python installed using pip (or easy install) are stored in the `Scripts`-subfolder of Python. In my case, this is `C:\Python27\Scripts`.

You should check, if your PATH-Environment containts that directory. Further information are [already on this SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9546324/2321643).

Comment: I have added the C:\Python27\Scripts to the path enviroment already. But inside C:\Python27\Scripts I couldn't find anything related to protobuf